# Setting common variable inside a php class

Tags: php, class

The following php class is written by me, it is working fine. However, I wish the code presentation can be more professional.

What is it doing?

- at the end of the codes, FULL_SEO_URL('xxxx') triggers function
  FULL_SEO_URL to operate a class;
- inside the class, the 2nd method will check itself for looping, and adopt the 1st method for some treatments;
- after 2nd method is done, the product will pass to 3rd method

What do I wish to ask?

- how can I global a variable inside the class, but out side the methods? (e.g. $all_seo_url_array), actually the variable is usable among all methods;
- how can I set the initial value of $k=0 inside the class? Actually I    also want to reset it to 0 for each FULL_SEO_URL('xxxx') usage;

Thanks.

```
<?php
$k = 0; //I don't like to set $k=0 here, but it is the only way to work
class CONVERT{  
    public static function parent_id_to_seo_url($page_id){
        $sql_parent_id_to_seo_url   = "select * from ".DB_PREFIX."page 
                                    left join ".DB_PREFIX."page_contents 
                                    on ".DB_PREFIX."page.page_id = ".DB_PREFIX."page_contents.page_id
                                    where ".DB_PREFIX."page.page_id = '".$page_id."'
                                    and ".DB_PREFIX."page_contents.language = '".$_SESSION['frontend']['lang']."'";
        $result_parent_id_to_seo_url = mysql_query($sql_parent_id_to_seo_url);
        $record_parent_id_to_seo_url = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_parent_id_to_seo_url);
        return $record_parent_id_to_seo_url['seo_url'];
    }

    public static function all_seo_url($single_seo_url){
        global $all_seo_url_array;    //can I global it outside the methods?
        global $k;    //can I global it outside the methods?

        $sql_all_seo_url        =   "select * from ".DB_PREFIX."page 
                                    left join ".DB_PREFIX."page_contents 
                                    on ".DB_PREFIX."page.page_id = ".DB_PREFIX."page_contents.page_id
                                    where ".DB_PREFIX."page_contents.seo_url = '".$single_seo_url."'
                                    and ".DB_PREFIX."page_contents.language = '".$_SESSION['frontend']['lang']."'";
        $result_all_seo_url     = mysql_query($sql_all_seo_url);
        $record_all_seo_url = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_all_seo_url);

        $all_seo_url_array[$k]['seo_url'] = $record_all_seo_url['seo_url'];

        $k++;

        if ($record_all_seo_url['level']>1){CONVERT::all_seo_url(CONVERT::parent_id_to_seo_url($record_all_seo_url['parent_id']));} else { $k = 0; }  //can I reset $k=0 at better place?

        return $all_seo_url_array;
    }

    public static function reverse_seo_url($all_seo_url_array){
        global $all_seo_url_array_reverse;   //can I global it outside the methods?

        $all_seo_url_array_reverse = array_reverse($all_seo_url_array);

        $final_url = '';
        foreach ($all_seo_url_array_reverse as $key => $value){
            $final_url  .= '/'.$all_seo_url_array_reverse[$key]['seo_url'];
        }   
        return $final_url;
    }

}

function FULL_SEO_URL($seo_url){
    return CONVERT::reverse_seo_url(CONVERT::all_seo_url($seo_url));
}

echo FULL_SEO_URL('history'); echo "<br/>";
echo FULL_SEO_URL('other-innovations'); echo "<br/>";
?>
```

Comment: This question qualifies for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ You should get more issues covered there not only a question (which is about *object property* I think)

Answer (score 0):

You can set static properties in a class like:

```
class myClass{
    public static $myProperty = 0;

    public static function myFunction(){
        echo self::$myProperty;
        self::$myProperty = 1;
        echo self::$myProperty;
    }

echo myClass::$myProperty;
# output: 0
myClass::myFunction();
# output 0 1
echo myClass::$myProperty;
# output 1
myClass::$myProperty=0;
echo myClass::$myProperty;
# output 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood what you mean by global regarding `$k`;

```
<?php

class CONVERT
{
    protected $k;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->k = 0;
    }
}
```

With this, you can use `$this->k` in all methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use constructor to access a variable across the the class.

EX.

```
class testclass
{
    private $global_variable;

    public function __construct($global_variable)
    {
       $this->global_variable = $global_variable;
    }

    public function yourmethod()
    {
       $this->global_variable; // And so on
    }
}
```